# If VBA multiple conditions

Tags: excel, if-statement, multiple-conditions, vba

I have a problem with my VBA code and instructions `IF`, I have to use a multi-conditionig, but VBA, if I check the condition 4 as true always ignores other conditions.

> ((Condition 1) or (Condition 2)) and (condition 3 or condition 4)

Needs to macro accepts only the specified options:

> ((TRUE) or (FALSE)) and (TRUE or FALSE)
>   ((TRUE) or (FALSE)) and (TRUE or TRUE)
>   ((FALSE) or (TRUE)) and (TRUE or FALSE)
>   ((FALSE) or (TRUE)) and (TRUE or TRUE)

There is real code:

```
If ((raport_glowny.Cells(i, R_delivedate_C).Value = CDate(Arkusz6.DeliveryDaySMS)) _
And (raport_glowny.Cells(i, R_deliverytime_C).Value >= CDate(Arkusz6.DeliveryHourSMS.Value))) _
Or ((raport_glowny.Cells(i, R_delivedate_C).Value = CDate(Arkusz6.DeliveryDaySMS) + 1) _
And (raport_glowny.Cells(i, R_deliverytime_C).Value < CDate(Arkusz6.DeliveryHourSMS.Value))) _
And ((raport_glowny.Cells(i, R_deliverytime_C).Value > 0) _
Or (Arkusz6.cbSMSforecast = True)) Then
```

If anyone can help I will be very grateful

Comment: What are the four conditions? From your `IF`-statement I interpret them as `condition1 = CBool([raport_glowny.Cells(i, R_delivedate_C) = Date(Arkusz6.DeliveryDaySMS)])`, `condition2 = CBool([raport_glowny.Cells(i, R_deliverytime_C >= CDate(Arkusz6.DeliveryHourSMS)])`, `condition3 = CBool([raport_glowny.Cells(i, R_deliverytime_C < CDate(Arkusz6.DeliveryHourSMS)])`, and `condition4 = CBool([raport_glowny.Cells(i, R_deliverytime_C).Value > 0])`. Is this correct?

Comment: You say "If condition 4 is true then ignore other conditions" but then below you have acceptable condition(s) where Condition 4 is false. Which is it? I notice that Condition 3 is always TRUE. Also what about (TRUE OR TRUE) AND (TRUE OR TRUE)? Is that a potential solution?

Comment: Might as well give sample data and expected result.

Comment: What you have right now is basically this: `If FirstCheck Or SecondCheck And ThirdCheck Then` ... Clearly this is an issue with parenthesis. You might consider breaking these boolean values out into functions to make it easier to read and then putting it back together afterwards. Also, I don't completely understand `(TRUE or TRUE)` as that last condition.

Comment: @eirikdaude, `condition1=((raport_glowny.Cells(i, R_delivedate_C).Value = CDate(Arkusz6.DeliveryDaySMS)) _
And (raport_glowny.Cells(i, R_deliverytime_C).Value >= CDate(Arkusz6.DeliveryHourSMS.Value))) , condition2=((raport_glowny.Cells(i, R_delivedate_C).Value = CDate(Arkusz6.DeliveryDaySMS) + 1) _
And (raport_glowny.Cells(i, R_deliverytime_C).Value < CDate(Arkusz6.DeliveryHourSMS.Value))), condition3=(raport_glowny.Cells(i, R_deliverytime_C).Value > 0), condition4=(Arkusz6.cbSMSforecast = True)

Comment: What about condition 4?

Comment: Condition4 is  Arkusz6.cbSMSforecast = True, "cbSMSforecast" is checkbox, and if i check this box them whole "if" is true

Comment: Then what are those 4 statements that you say your code has to comply with? I assumed that was what you put your condition into in order?